# SharpSVN Sync Command C#

Tags: c#, svn, sharpsvn, svnsync

I am trying to automate a svnsync init and svnsync sync process via sharpsvn.
I am unable to find any documentation regarding svnsync on the provided docs.

So far I am able to successfully create a repository by doing this:

```
SvnRepositoryClient src = new SvnRepositoryClient();
src.CreateRepository(RepoDir + RepoName);
```

Am I doing something wrong? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

The svnsync featureset is not exposed as a library by Subversion, so there is no way to call in something that does not exist. Sorry.